# How to use form_set_error if no form field is involved in the error?

Tags: 7, forms

In a form_validate hook, I have some custom validation and I'm using

```
form_set_error('field_foo', "error_message");
```

to show validation errors. If the validation returns an error that is not linked to a particular form field, how do I show the error, indipendently? (For example: the error is you compiled more that three times the form.)

EDIT: I though to use:

```
drupal_set_message("error_message", 'error');
```

From the documentaion for 7.x

> When a validation error is detected, the validator calls
>   form_set_error() to indicate which element needs to be changed and
>   provide an error message.

So, form_set_error() produce an error linked to a particular field of the form. I needed to display error indipendently in a custom complex validation, being errors not really about a field. I though to use form_set_error() on a random field, but it is not the perfect solution, for the field was highlighted and only the last error produced this way was visible.
drupal_set_message solves this two problem, but the validation success and the form continues like there was no error.

Answer (score 1):

The way core Drupal does this is to use `''` for the first parameter of `form_set_error()`. So in the example you give, `form_set_error('', "error_message");` would set the error message for the form, not tied to any specific form element.

This is an undocumented feature of `form_set_error()`, but it's a feature that core Drupal has used forever, over many different versions of Drupal core (including the current Drupal 9 version!). There is currently an issue open in the core Drupal issue queue asking for this feature to be documented. See https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2780209

Answer (score 0):

There is a plain solution

```
form_set_error('form',$error_messages);
```

Does not highlight any field, and the validation fails as expected. It doesn't allow multiple message, but this can be solved using a little hack

```
$error_messages = "";
if (type_error_1)
   $error_messages .= "Error Message on First Line <br/>";
}
if (type_error_2){
   $error_messages .= "Error Message on Another Line <br/>";
}
if(strlen($error_messages) > 0){
  form_set_error('form',$error_messages);
}
```